# Django one-to-many relations in a template

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am searching of a method to obtain html forms from some one-to-many relations, like order-lineorder, invoice-lineinvoice, etc.

Let me an example:

```
# models.py
class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class LineOrder(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)

# views.py
def order_form(request):
    form = OrderForm()
    table_lineorder = LineOrderTable([])
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, "order_form.html", {"form": form, "table": table_lineorder})
```

Then, I want to obtain the order template with "generic attributes" (date, number), and a table list (originally empty) of lines order. Add some action like add, edit and remove must be possible.

I think that a solution like django-tables2 is possible, but I can't add rows dinamically, I think.

Thanks in advice.

[EDIT]

I have found the solution. It is [django-dynamic-formset](https://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear about your question, but I guess this might be what you want:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    items = model.ManyToManyField(Item)

class Item(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
```

It should be equivalent to one-to-many if you don't assign one `Item` to multiple `Order`s.

Comment: I don't mean to change model. Order - LineOrder model is ok. I mean to obtain html code to insert lines order.